# Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer throws no report instance error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, telerik

I am trying to display the telerik HTML5 report viewer widget on my MVC 4 project.  I have the report viewer defined in a partial div as follows.

```
@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
    .Id("reportViewer1")
    .ServiceUrl("/api/reports/")
    .TemplateUrl("/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html")
    .ReportSource(new TypeReportSource() { TypeName = "DialerReports.ReportCatalog, DialerReports" })
    .ViewMode(ViewModes.INTERACTIVE)
    .ScaleMode(ScaleModes.SPECIFIC)
    .Scale(1.0)
    .PersistSession(false)
```

)

I followed the guides on the telerik site to set up the projects so yes the javascript files are included.  I did place them in the MVC bundles rather than directly, but am unsure if this would make a difference.

The problem I am having is this. When the web page loads an error is thrown from the Report Viewer.js file of JavaScript runtime error: No Report instance.   I'm using the 8.0.14 version of the Report viewer, and I know the error means the instance is undefined, but I cannot figure out exactly where the report instance is defined to fix this issue.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using ASP .Net MVC 4 project template - it comes with jQuery v1.7.1. Telerik reporting needs  at least jQuery v1.9. I updated jQuery to 2.1 - and js runtime error was gone.

Comment: Yeah Telerik support suggested that too, I'll post what the solution turned out to be below

Answer (score 1):

Ok this problem was actually caused because i changed the default route in the routeconfig.cs file to be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionsApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Actions",
            id = RouteParameter.Optional, id1 = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 =     RouteParameter.Optional, id3 = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

then added the default route config you are supposed to have after this as another route.  The problem was actually that the telerik report viewer api was trying to use the routepath above rather than the correct one that was another path.  Jquery was actually throwing the correct error, because there was no report instance coming from the reporting api.